# Aumentar espaços quando diminuímos página

Tags: html, css

Estou a criar uma página em HTML5 onde quero colocar o tamanho da página correcta para todos os tipos de utilização, ou seja, a pagina aparecer correcta independentemente do tamanho do ecrã.

Quando reduzo a página HTML acontece isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em css como consigo corrigir esta situação?

Comment: Como você quer que seja o resultado final? A dica é não usar pixels como unidade. Use `%` ou `em` ou qualquer outra unidade de medida relativa. De uma olhada também em frameworks css, como o [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) e o [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Comment: Queres corrigir apensa essa situação do espaçamento entre texto? Eu recomendava-te usar [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) que faz esse trabalho por ti.

Comment: Apenas quero que o espaço em branco aumente para continuar o texto na parte em branco

Answer (score 2):

Use % ao invés de px. Estude layouts fluídos ou media query. Caso queira usar um framework front-end eu recomendo o bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu compreendi bem o seu layout, tanto a barra no topo quanto a barra no rodapé estão fixas. Você não tem como *aumentar* o espaço do conteúdo. O que dá pra fazer é adicionar as barras de scroll quando necessário.

Veja um exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ev9mhj5p/3/). O css está comentado para entender melhor o exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho você a estudar layouts fluidos. Mas começar usando `%` ao invés de `px` nos seus `margins` e `paddings`, já é um ótimo começo.